# How can I create an array of objects from a list of associated checkboxes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, routes, checkbox

First of all, I've done a fair amount of looking around, and while questions get around answers, I have a problem I think is somewhat unique. I have a list of checkboxes generated with the following code:

```
<% for student in Student.find(:all) %>
    <div>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[student_ids][]", student.id, current_user.students.include    (student) %>
    <%= student.name %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

After clicking the 'update' button at the bottom, I need each of the checked boxes to be placed into an array. I then plan on iterating over the array and doing some work on each of the checked names. I am having a hard time, however, with the process of getting these names all into an array. I really am not sure which of the standard web actions this kind of work should be (i.e, post, get, etc.), so I don't know how to set up a route. Even if I could set up a route to a controller, how would I get the checked students into an array of Student objects?

Thanks ahead of time for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem in a less-than-satisfying way. Here is the code I ended up using:

```
current_user.students.delete_all
  if(params.has_key? :user)
     params[:user][:student_ids].each do |i|
        current_user.students<<(Student.find(i))
     end
  end
```

Because the number of students I'm managing is not ever larger than 100, this operation isn't as bad as it looks. I'm deleting all of the associations already present, and then cycling through all passed parameters. I then find the student object with the passed parameter id and add it to the current_user's User-Student join table.

I hope this helps someone down the line!

Answer (score 0):

The full answer to your question depends on a variety of things, for example, what you are trying to do with the submitted array, etc (which would determine whether POST, GET, PUT or DELETE should be used.)  Without knowing more information with respect to your code base, if you throw the following code into a form_for in one of your controller's already restful routes, you should be able to see the array of checked names:

```
<%= current_user.students.include(student).each do |student| %>
    <div>
        <%= check_box_tag "student_names[]", student.name %> <%= label_tag student.name %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Then, when the user hits submit, the params hash will show student_names = [].

And make sure your attributes are accessible as needed.

On a side note, check out Railscasts pro episode from last week.  Pretty much exactly explains what you are trying to do.  It's a subscription service, though.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! After I get the array, I'm planning on cycling through it and checking to see if each Student is already involved in the HABTM relationship between Users and Students. If the student is not already associated, I need it to create the association. If it is associated, I want it to do nothing. I have the code to do that bit (or, at least, I know how and have been able to do such with the Rails Console), but I need to get the array of chosen students to some controller, do that work, and refresh the view.